# How to collapse programmatically all panels in a primefaces accordionPanel?

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a primefaces accordion panel in a primefaces dialog, and ithat every time the dialog (dialog is dynamic="true") is open all the panels of the accordionPanel are collapsed.

The accordionPanel has a peculiarity, it can have from 0 to 2 panels and this is not known until the moment in which the user clicks on a menuItem. The existence or not of these panels depends on the existence of 2 objects in the backing bean.

My code:

```
<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="-1" dynamic="true" widgetVar="accordionPanelWV" id="accordionPanel">
    <p:tab title="#{messages['comun.provA']}" rendered="#{productsBean.productSel.providerA != null}">
        ....
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="#{messages['comun.provB']}" rendered="#{productsBean.productSel.providerB != null}">
        ....
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

I have tried the following but none of it has given me the expected result

*Select an negative, null or not valid index in JS/Jquery before open/close the dialog*

```
PF('accordionPanelWV').select(-1);
PF('accordionPanelWV').select(null);
PF('accordionPanelWV').select("");
```

*Unselect all index in JS/Jquery before open/close the dialog*

```
PF('accordionPanelWV').unselect(0);
PF('accordionPanelWV').unselect(1);
```

How can I do this?

Primefaces version 8.0

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in PF 9.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6605

To add `selectAll` and `unselectAll` methods to expand all or collapse all panels just add this JS code to your application.

```js
if (PrimeFaces.widget.AccordionPanel) {
    PrimeFaces.widget.AccordionPanel.prototype.selectAll = function() {
        var $this = this;
        this.panels.each(function(index) {
            $this.select(index);
            if (!$this.cfg.multiple) {
                return false; // breaks
            }
        });
    };

    PrimeFaces.widget.AccordionPanel.prototype.unselectAll = function() {
        var $this = this;
        this.panels.each(function(index) {
            $this.unselect(index);
        });
    };
}
```